# Define Complex MAP with default values

Tags: apex

Is it possible to define a complex map with default value

eg. a simple map can be defined as

```
Map<String, String> MyStrings = new Map<String, String>{'a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'};
```

My Map is

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes e.g.:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>>  m = new Map<String, Map<String, String>>{
        'a' => new Map<String, String>{'x1' => '1', 'y1' => '2'},
        'b' => new Map<String, String>{'x2' => '1', 'y2' => '2'}
        };
```